# Add Search Engine into MVC Music Store

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

i'm trying to add search the title plus genre drop down list inside store in mvc music store. here's the procedure i've done

firstly i'v added the below code into the StoreManagere controller

```
public ActionResult SearchIndex(string musicGenre, string searchString)
    {

        var GenreLST = new List<string>();

        var GenreQry = from d in db.Genres
                       orderby d.Name
                       select d.Name;

        GenreLST.AddRange(GenreQry.Distinct());
        ViewBag.movieGenre = new SelectList(GenreLST);

        var musics = from m in db.Albums.Include(a => a.Genre).Include(a => a.Artist)
                     select m;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            musics = musics.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(musicGenre))
            return View(musics);
        else
        {
            return View(musics.Where(x => x.Genre.Name == musicGenre));
        }

    }
```

and the below code inside search index view page

```
    @model IEnumerable<MvcMusicStore.Models.Album>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SearchIndex";

}

<h2>SearchIndex</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
            <p>Genre : @Html.DropDownList("musicGenre", "All")
            Title : @Html.TextBox("searchString")
            <input type="submit" value="Filetr" /></p>
    }
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Genre
        </th>
        <th>
            Artist
        </th>
        <th>
            Title
        </th>
        <th>
            Price
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Artist.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.AlbumId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.AlbumId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.AlbumId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

but i get this error

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'musicGenre'.

Comment: Since you have it right in the model, try @Html.DropDownList(Model, "All")

Comment: @NeilN - It is not really in the model though, it is here: `ViewBag.movieGenre = new SelectList(GenreLST);`.

Comment: Yes, because it IS the model.  The object he is trying to use for the drop down is what he passed in as the model.

Comment: @NeilN - The model is a list of album objects with their associated genres and artists. It is conditionally filtered by `Title`. It is not a list of movie genres.

Comment: Thanks Guys i've mistakenly added movie instead of music. thanks to all of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You saved your genre list in ViewBag.movieGenre not musicGenre.  That's why it is not working.